# XSLT failure when using xsl:choose to test results from xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an `xsl:for-each` which pulls together a number of different elements, and then conditionally processes each. For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//del | .//sup | .//unc | .//gap">
   <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="del"><xsl:text>Output foo del</xsl:text></xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="sup"><xsl:text>Output foo sup</xsl:text></xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="unc"><xsl:text>Output foo unc</xsl:text></xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="gap"><xsl:text>Output foo gap</xsl:text></xsl:when> 
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>For each works, but the tests do not!</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
<xsl:for-each>
```

The `<xsl:for-each>` is working fine, because it's outputting a lot of `<otherwise> For each works, but the tests do not!` Somehow I've misunderstood how to write the `@test` to catch each element? I think it has to do with the current context?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use an `xsl:for-each` with nested `xsl:choose/xsl:when` node tests instead of pushing the nodes to matching templates with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select=".//del | .//sup | .//unc | .//gap"/>` and then have e.g. `<xsl:template match="del">Output foo del</xsl:template>` and so on for the other element types?

Comment: Yes, these are being brought together in one physical section, counted and assigned a number for footnotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but shouldn't it read like this?

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//del | .//sup | .//unc | .//gap">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::del"><xsl:text>Output foo del</xsl:text></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::sup"><xsl:text>Output foo sup</xsl:text></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::unc"><xsl:text>Output foo unc</xsl:text></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::gap"><xsl:text>Output foo gap</xsl:text></xsl:when> 
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>For each works, but the tests do not!</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
<xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, you would have to declare `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` e.g. within `choose` or even `for-each`.

Comment: Sorry, that was just my typo here - my actual code has `xsl:` in all the elements. I've corrected the code above. Any ideas why the XPATH I've put in  `@test` does not catch the respective element?

Comment: Try `self::del` etc. Inserted that in my answer. For further questions: It would be helpful to see more sample xml code, current results and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to `test="self::del"` as suggested in another answer fixes the problem, but the idiomatic way to do this in XSLT is with template rules:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".//*" mode="m"/>
```

then

```
<xsl:template match="del" mode="m">Output foo del</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="sup" mode="m">Output foo sup</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="unc" mode="m">Output foo unc</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="gap" mode="m">Output foo gap</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="m">Otherwise</xsl:template>
```